# Contact Database Design

Tags: database-design, android-contacts

I want to design he database for mobile contacts. here is the link to see what i designed already:

http://upload7.ir/images/87645261298795662612.jpg

Here is my sample! Its not complete but it's just a little try. I have a problem here! I want to have unlimited Fax numbers or Phone numbers, etc.

with this design can't! Is there anyway to add another column after design?

or I must totally change this?

if i changed this what should i do? take another table and take all phone numbers in it and add 1 column to get information about its Phone/Fax/Mobile? If i do this there is always a Data that keep repeating in my Database and its not good! looking for another suggestion.

Thanks :-)

Comment: Yes, you can take one another table Contact Numbers (Id, ContactID(foreign key, taken from Contacts table), Number, Type(Fax/ Phone/ Mobile), Details). In this ContactID repeats every time but it would be much better than taking 3 tables separately and this is the normalized way to handle multiple data related to same Contact. Your concern or other suggestions would be appreciated here.

Comment: but this Database ganna be for Mobile Contacts! I think if we going to use that kind of Table it will make our Database slow! because  if we have 10000 Records or more, and we want to add 1 more mobile for Contact #1 it will be at the end of the table and it will make abit delay for our program to fine that record.

if we use Specific table for each type of numbers it will make our search faster and we can get better queries as we can have indexed table only for Mobile numbers which can be use finding people by their phone numbers or more options.

Thank you again Ankit Arora

Comment: btw, when i said that there is the field that which always keep repeating was Type Field. For each Contact u should keep give Records like this:

1, 1, 123456, Mobile
2, 1, 123457, Mobile
3, 2, 123333, Mobile

as you can see mobile field keep repeating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common design for holding mobile/fax/etc. numbers.  Every user can have as many mobile/fax/phone records as needed. You might want to change the numbers table, here in the U.S. a phone number looks like this: 1-234-567-9876. The `1` is the country code, `234` is the "area code", `567` is the "exchange" and `9876` is the "station". I use `char` data types in case I have to store a number with a leading 0.

```
number_types
    id              unsigned int(P)
    description     varchar(15)

+----+-------------+
| id | description |
+----+-------------+
|  1 | Mobile      |
|  2 | Phone       |
|  3 | Fax         |
| .. | ........... |
+----+-------------+

numbers
    id              unsigned int(P)
    country_code    char(3)
    area_code       char(3)
    exchange        char(3)
    station         char(4)
    extension       varchar(10) // Default to NULL

+----+--------------+-----------+----------+---------+-----------+
| id | country_code | area_code | exchange | station | extension |
+----+--------------+-----------+----------+---------+-----------+
|  1 |           98 |        21 |      555 |    5555 | NULL      |
|  1 |           01 |       555 |      555 |    5555 | NULL      |
| .. | ............ | ......... | ........ | ....... | ......... |
+----+--------------+-----------+----------+---------+-----------+

users
    id              unsigned int(P)
    first_name      varchar(30)
    last_name       varchar(30)
    ...

+----+------------+-----------+-----+
| id | first_name | last_name | ... |
+----+------------+-----------+-----+
|  1 | Saroukhani | Smith     | ... |
|  2 | Benny      | Hill      | ... |
| .. | .......... | ......... | ... |
+----+------------+-----------+-----+

users_numbers
    id                  unsigned int(P)
    user_id             unsigned int(F users.id)
    number_id           unsigned int(F numbers.id)
    number_type_id      unsigned int(F number_types.id)

+----+---------+-----------+----------------+
| id | user_id | number_id | number_type_id |
+----+---------+-----------+----------------+
|  1 |       1 |         1 |              1 |
|  2 |       2 |         2 |              1 |
| .. | ....... | ......... | .............. |
+----+---------+-----------+----------------+
```